# Change the order of event handling in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a Suggest box which has 2 hadlers: `SelectionHandler` for selecting items in `SuggestionList` and `keyDownHandler` on `TextBox` of `SuggestBox`. I want to prevent default action on event(for example on Enter pressed) when the suggestion list is currently showing. The problem is that `SelectionEvent` is always fires before `KeyDownEvent` and suggestion list is closed after `SuggestionEvent` fired, so in `KeyDownEventHandler` suggestion list is already closed. And I can't use prevent default action on Enter with checking the suggestion list is showing like this:

```
if ((nativeCode == KeyCodes.KEY_TAB || nativeCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) && display.isSuggestionListShowing()) {
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

where `display.isSuggestionListShowing()` is the method which calls `isShowing` on `SuggestBox` .
So how can i change the order of event handling(`Selection` before `KeyDown` to the `keyDown` before `Selection`) in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean `SuggestBox` instead of `SuggestionList`, as there is no class by that name in the gwt-user jar.

The `SuggestBox` uses the keydown event to provide the SelectEvent - if it can't see the keys change (from the browser, which actually picks up the user's action), it can't provide the logical selection event.

This means that reordering events doesn't really make sense - you can't have the effect before the cause. In many cases, the browser emits events in a certain order, and there is no way to change this, so you have to think differently about the problem.

(Also worth pointing out that preventDefault() only prevents the browser from doing its default behavior - other handlers will still fire as normal.)

One option would be to preview all events before they get to the SuggestBox, and cancel the event in certain cases - look into `com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.addNativePreviewHandler(NativePreviewHandler)` for how this can be done.

I'm not seeing any other option right away - all of the actual logic for handling the keydown is wrapped up in the inner class in the private method of `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.addEventsToTextBox()`, leaving no options for overriding it.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution of the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information as to why this didn't work or you can't use it? The main other option I'm seeing at a glance would be to make your own version of SuggestBox (also, can you confirm that you meant SuggestBox), as the origional isn't exactly suited to be modified like this.